# Get a row from excel file which contains a value

Tags: java

I need to get a row which contains value in column 1 in my excel file using Java

I need to search column when find cell then get the row which contains searched cell

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
XSSFWorkbook workBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
XSSFSheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt (0);

List<XSSFRow> filteredRows = new ArrayList<XSSFRow>();
Iterator<Row> rows= sheet.rowIterator(); 
while (rows.hasNext ()){
    XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next ();
    for(Cell cell : row) {
    if(cell.getColumnIndex() == 1) {
       // process a cell in column 1
       if (cell.getStringCellValue()!=null){
          String val = cell.getStringCellValue();
          if (val.equals(""))
              //You will find valid value in variable val
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: if (val.equals("")) here i need to write the value wchich i looking for ? in this "" ?

Comment: Hey @RafałSurdziel can you please mark it as final answer if it solved your issue.